# Accumulate all keys at the same path

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, nested

I have this nested dict with recurring keys:

```
{
   "name":A,
   "children":[
      {
         "name":B,
         "id":0B
      },
      {
         "name":C
         "children":[
            {
               "name":D,
               "id":0D
            },
            {
               "name":E,
               "id":0E
            },
           
         ],
         "id":0C
      }
   ],
   "id":0A
}
```

What I want to get, is something like this:

```
[0A,0A>0B,0A>0C,0A>0C>0D,0A>0C>0E]
```

This is the best code that works for me, it gives a list of all the keys and still respect the hierarchy. But I couldn't modify it correctly to accumulate the keys by depth.

```
def findkeys(node, kv):
    if isinstance(node, list):
        for i in node:
            for x in findkeys(i, kv):
               yield x
    elif isinstance(node, dict):
        if kv in node:
            yield node[kv]
        for j in node.values():
            for x in findkeys(j, kv):
                yield x 
    print(list(findkeys(data, 'name')))
```

Comment: Could you clarify why your expected output contains `0A>0B>0C` instead of `0A>0C` etc. Because `0C` isn't a child of `0B`

Comment: I edited it, thank you for letting me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following recursive generator works:

```
def build_paths(d):
    yield d['id']
    if 'children' in d:
        for child in d['children']:
            yield from (d['id'] + '>' + cp for cp in build_paths(child))

path_lst = [p for p in build_paths(d)]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Way easier and clearer. Thank you very much!